# What's going on behind the scenes in "".join(e[0] for e in phrase.split())?

Tags: python, string, list, split, substring

I am a beginner trying to learn Python when my limited experience is in Java, so bear with me here.

I can pick apart what the purpose of each part of the code is. I understand that we are joining essentially the first character of each word in a phrase into a string, effectually making an acronym as a result. I understand that we need to parse the phrase into a list of words, and that for each word we can pop off the first character, and that we need a loop to do that. Okay, makes sense.

But what the heck? We're passing a for loop into a join function? And how does the e[0] play in here, when it's syntactically not a part of the the for loop, that I can see?

I think maybe the syntax is throwing me for a loop (pardon the pun).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#rationale). It's similar to a [list comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/#rationale), except it uses `()` instead of `[]`, and evaluates to a generator instead of a list. It can also make use of existing `()`, like the ones used to call `join`.

```
"".join(e[0] for e in phrase.split())
```

Is essentially equivalent to:

```
"".join([e[0] for e in phrase.split()])  # A list comprehension
```

Or, spelled out entirely using a typical `for` loop:

```
chars = []

for e in phrase.split():
    chars.append(e[0])

"".join(chars)
```